# If i pass a lambda as a listener, can I remove the listener from inside the lambda

Tags: android, lambda, listener

In an android app, I have the following method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    final View view = getView();
    if (view == null) return;
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
        view.post(() -> {
            if (mIsTablet) {
                mImageFlipper.getLayoutParams().height =
                        ViewUtil.setHeightForAspectRatio(view.getWidth(), ViewUtil.PORTRAIT);
            } else {
                mImageFlipper.getLayoutParams().height =
                        ViewUtil.setHeightForAspectRatio(mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels, ViewUtil.PORTRAIT);
            }
            view.getViewTreeObserver();
        });

    });
}
```

The thing is, I love lambdas. They are concise, they are clean and expressive.

However, after the listener is triggered, I would like to remove (preferably from inside the lambda itself).

The question is simple: how can I remove the listener?

A little more abstract question would be: how can I reference a lambda from within itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

> **Accessing Local Variables of the Enclosing Scope**
>   Like local and anonymous classes, lambda expressions can capture
>   variables; they have the same access to local variables of the
>   enclosing scope. However, unlike local and anonymous classes, lambda
>   expressions do not have any shadowing issues (see Shadowing for more
>   information). Lambda expressions are lexically scoped. This means that
>   **they do not inherit any names from a supertype or introduce a new
>   level of scoping**

I think it means you just can't reference the lambda from within itself.
To solve your problem I think you should create assign the lambda to a variable and reference the variable from within the lambda

```
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener layoutListener;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    layoutListener = () -> {
        // ...
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener);
    };
```

or just give up the lambda this time...